# How to open external url with POST method from IONIC..?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, ionic-framework

I Have CodeIgniter Controller On server to create Excel file, and running well on Web with submit form method, how to run or execute it controller from my IONIC..?

below my code igniter controller,

```
function excel_kpa(){
    $kat2='KPA_K';
    $kat2b='KPA_P';
    $nik=$this->input->post('hdNik'); //from submit form 
    $nama=$this->input->post('hdNama'); //from submit form 
    $varJawab1 = $this->m_master_indikator->get_hasil_bobot($nik, 1, $kat2);
    $varJawab23 = $this->m_master_indikator->get_hasil_bobot($nik, 23, $kat2);

    $this->load->library('Excel');

    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("template/kpa.xlsx");

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('M5', $varJawab1) 
                ->setCellValue('M31', $varJawab23);

    //ob_end_clean();

    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'  . $nama . '-' . $nik .  '.xlsx' . '"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you can do using $http.

method:-

1)

```
app.controller("mycontroller",function($scope,$http){
  $http.post("www.google.com",{page:'akjbd',state:'true'}).then(function(res){
    console.log(res.data); // it will print result from url
  })
});
```

2)

```
 app.controller("mycontroller",function($scope,$http){
  $http.get("www.google.com?page=akjbd&state=true").then(function(res){
    console.log(res.data); // it will print result from url
  })
});
```

[for $http demo](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp)

thank you.......